# Сталий вираз на позначення (дуже) віддаленого місця

Tags: from-english, фразеологізми

Цікавлять усталені вирази, що дозволяють описувати географічну віддаленість якогось об’єкта. Спіймала себе на думці, що не можу легко передати українською англійський вираз `in the middle of nowhere`.

Варіанти, які спали на думку:

- [`Богом забуте місце`](https://english.com.ua/uk/blog/9-anglijskikh-idiom-dlya-opisu-mist-podij-i-mists.html)
- `серед степу`([тут](http://day.kyiv.ua/uk/article/kultura/koncert-sered-stepu) дещо менш метафорично, бо справді йдеться про подію у степу, [тут](https://sites.google.com/site/komplib/home/legendi-krau) також степова географія має місце)

Перший варіант мене не дуже влаштовує, бо а) згадується бог і б) потенційна забутість кимось місця не обов’язково означає його віддаленість. Другий же варіант наприклад буде дуже недоречним при описі якогось віддаленого гірського села, де степу й близько немає.

Comment: Як щодо *край світа*?

Comment: Ще є дуже колоритне *галасвіта*. [1](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghalasvita) [2](https://www.facebook.com/chystamova/photos/a.309176152571835.1073741828.303942943095156/801914483297997/?type=3&theater)

Answer (score 7):

1. [далеко](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=97) на rozum.org.ua

> (на великій відстані від кого-, чого-небудь) **на краю світу (світа);
>   не близький світ; близький (близенький,** діал. **блигий, блигомий)
>   світ,** ірон.; **близька сторона; у тридев’ятім (у тридев’ятому, у
>   тридесятому, у якомусь) царстві,** нар.-поет., **за тридев’ять (за
>   сім, за тридесять) земель,** нар.-поет.; **за горами й долами,**
>   нар.-поет.; **морем (за морями); за горами;** (у глухому, необжитому
>   місці, груб., фам.) **у чорта на болоті (на куличках); у чорта (у
>   дідька) в зубах (на рогах);** (в суворих необжитих краях, ірон.) **де
>   козам роги правлять (утинають); де Сидір козам роги править; де волам
>   роги правлять, а кіз кують підковами;** (у найвіддаленіших краях,
>   нар.-поет.) **куди ворон і кісток не заносить (не занесе, не донесе,
>   не доносив); де Макар телят пасе (не пас); куди (де) Макар телят не
>   ганяв (не гонить);** (так далеко, скільки можна бачити) **скільки
>   (куди, доки) око (зір) сягає (дістає, загляне, огляне, сягне, охоплює
>   і т. ін.): скільки ока.**

2. [«у чорта на болоті» значення](http://dovidka.biz.ua/u-chorta-na-boloti-znachennya/) на dovidka.biz.ua

> - на краю світу;
> - не близький світ;
> - у тридев’ятім (у тридев’ятому, у тридесятому, у якомусь) царстві,
> - за тридев’ять (за сім, за тридесять) земель,
> - за горами й долами,  за горами;
> - у чорта (у дідька) в зубах (на рогах);
> - де козам роги правлять (утинають);
> - де Сидір козам роги править;
> - де волам роги правлять, а кіз кують підковами;
> - куди ворон і кісток не заносить (не занесе, не донесе, не доносив);
> - де Макар телят пасе (не пас);
> - куди (де) Макар телят не ганяв (не гонить).

Answer (score 2):

За тридев'ять земель, за тридесят земель, у тридесятому царстві тощо, де дідько 'надобраніч' каже, в чорта на кулічках (не знаю, що таке кулічки, щоправда:))

Comment: Додайте будь ласка посилання на словники, де є ці слова, або де є приклади використання, бо без посилань відповіді вважаються на цьому сайті неповноцінними. Подробиці [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/69).

Comment: @Artemix, джерело — українські народні казки :)